# show a text instead of NULL value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

3.5 and want to show a text instead of NULL value in my category_id field

```
     <% if  e.categories_id == "NULL" %>
         <%= e.categories_id ="Don't have value"  %> 

     <% else %>
         <%= e.categories_id ="Has value"  %> 
     <% end %>
```

Someone can help me please?

I have tried

```
   <% if  e.categories_id =   NULL  %>
   <% if  e.categories_id ==  NULL  %>
   <% if  e.categories_id =  "NULL" %>
   <% if  e.categories_id == "NULL" %>
```

Comment: have you tried nil or empty? so if e.categories_id.empty?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= e.categories_id.nil? ? "Don't have value" : "Has value" %>
```

or even better:

```
<%= e.categories_id ? "Has value" : "Don't have value" %>
```

Comment: I would say only.. LOLzz :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= e.categories_id || "There's no categories_id" %>
```

But seriously, there's so much that's bad about this question. Firstly, you should know enough Ruby to know that it uses `nil` not `NULL`. A foreign key called `categories_id` suggest you have a model called `Categories`. Model names should be singular.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if e.categories_id.blank? %>
     <p>"Don't have value" </p> (or whatever you want displayed)
 <% else %>
     <%= e.categories_id %> (should display the value of e.categories_id)
 <% end %>
```

I prefer the .blank? method that Rails uses to check for both .empty? and .nil? Plus using an if else is more readable than the Terinary operator ? :

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you only want to display "Don't have value" if that is the case:

```
<%= e.categories_id || "Don't have value" %>
```

What you could do was to set the value:

```
<% e.categories_id ||= "Don't have value" %>
<%= e.categories_id %>
```

If you want to change the value of the data, you should not do that in the view. You should do all the data-manipulation in the controllers or even better, the model ([fat model, skinny controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/)).

There is one other issue you are having: In Ruby `null` is called `nil`. So a test for nil would look like this:

```
if whatever == nil
   #Do anything
end
```

What is nice about Ruby is that `nil` is considered as false in a statement, so you can omit the `== nil` so you get:

```
if whatever
   #Do anything
end
```